# Discord 2.0 Purging message (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

Im writing a simple discord bot that purges my channel's message.
But Im getting error and I dont know how to figure out what caused it.
Here's the entire code.

```
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.Commands
Imports Discord.WebSocket

<Group("purge")>
Public Class cmd_testcmd
    Inherits ModuleBase
    <Command>
    Public Async Function DelMsg(amount As Integer) As Task

        Try

            Dim msgs = Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount)
            Dim msg As IMessage = msgs

            Await msg.DeleteAsync(Await msgs.FlattenAsync)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("[Test] " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

So, when I type !purge 99 it should delete 99 messages.
Error:

```
[Test] Unable to cast object of type 'Concat2AsyncIterator`1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[Discord.IMessage]]' to type 'Discord.IMessage'.
```

Comment: You should add the exception you're getting

Comment: Error: [Test] Unable to cast object of type 'Concat2AsyncIterator`1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[Discord.IMessage]]' to type 'Discord.IMessage'.

Comment: You need to append FlattenAsync after the GetMessagesAsync method and await it.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to cast object of type 'Concat2AsyncIterator1[System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection1[Discord.IMessage]]' to type 'Discord.IMessage'

As the error clearly states: msgs is not a single IMessage but a Collection of IMessage

```
Dim msgs = Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(amount)
Dim msg As IEnumerable(of IMessage) = Await msgs.FlattenAsync()

Await Context.Channel.DeleteAsync(msg)
```

Comment: I get an error, using your example.
'DeleteAsync' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(OF Imessage)'.

Comment: now it should word, might still neet a cast from Context.Channel to ITextChannel.

Comment: `Await Context.Channel.DeleteAsync(msg)` Error. DeleteAsync is not part of IChannel.